# Get top players from the MySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, unique, distinct

I have table in MySQL DB which contains among other things two fields `user_id` and `score`. This table is kind of log table so there can be multiple rows for one user_id with different scores. How can I get only top 10 users with highest score from this table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM your_table
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM your_table
WHERE (user_id, score) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS score
                           FROM your_table
                           GROUP BY user_id)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65aaf/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: I also need to get result for scores, not only the user_id column. I need * fields to be returned. This query is not working.

Comment: Do I need to add some index or something to user_id column because this query doesn't work. It returns 10 rows but there are one user with 3 rows (3 different scores) and other user with 2 rows (2 different scores). I need just unique users.

Comment: @quarky See query in edit part. `DISTINCT` will remove duplicates. Should I prepare demo?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic and you should put more effort; here is atemplate you can use -

```
SELECT TOP 10 distinct * 
FROM people 
WHERE names='SMITH'
ORDER BY names asc
```